# How to install a package from launchpad which doesn't belong to a PPA?

Tags: apt, repository, launchpad

I am running Kubuntu 12.10 (quantal) and I want to install ike-qtgui, available in launchpad at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/ike-qtgui

The package is not part of a PPA, but it is not in the official repository. Can I configure apt to use the "root" launchpad as a package source? Is the only solution to download the .deb file and install it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package was deleted from the repositories, I doubt you can find it anywhere using apt-get. [Here is the notice](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/ike/2.1.7+dfsg-1.1):

[image]

Comment: @Fred Braiam has it right, you can't get it anywhere with apt-get.  Since the code was not maintained and was an old version of QT3, it was removed, and the only way you're going to get this is by manually downloading and installing an OLD version of the package from Debian.  However, note that the package is also removed in Debian as well, so you'll have to do a lot of digging to grab the package.

Comment: Braiaim, I forgot to put the @ there to ping him, with the @ there he will get pinged.  However, I did want to confirm your answer.  :)